# Fast way to convert large vectorial images to binary matrix

Tags: c#, image-processing, graphics, rasterizing

I have complex vectorial images I need to convert to binary matrix (a kind of rasterizing) with high precision, using necessarily c#. Currently I'm doing it by painting vectorial images in a bitmap and reading the internal bitmap array. Then I convert this array in a binary matrix where 1 indicates that the corresponding pixel is of a specific color, and 0 when is not. As I access the internal bitmap array directly, that's fast and allows using `Parallel.For` 
The problem is that I need to obtain very high definition matrixes of the images (50000x25000 or more). Therefore I have to paint each vectorial image dividing it in several parts, as a bitmap of this size is not supported.
As I have a lot of images to convert, it is very slow.
I'm looking for a fast way of doing that without loosing precision (ideally even increasing it). And I need to integrate this feature in a c# application.

Comment: I suspect that [OpenCV](https://opencv.org/) should be able to handle this

Comment: Can you say more about the format or type of vector information you have? What bpp format bitmap are you using? I can create `new Bitmap(50000,25000,PixelFormat.Format1bppIndexed)` without issue in 64-bit .Net.

Comment: Another possibility is apparently using WIC with `System.Windows.Media.Imaging`, which apparently is a bit slow to start but then should be okay.

Comment: Hi, answering to NetMage: I need to paint vectorial polygon data in a bitmap using different colors, because next I read bitmap pixels to find those of some specific colors. The idea is converting  some polygons to a binary matrix, but those polygons may be partially hiden by other ones. So I paint all polygons using different colors and in a specific order, then I find the pixels of a specific color in the resulting bitmap. Therefore I need to use at least 256 colors.

Comment: @modestprog, you can (1) split images, then (2) convert each piece into binary using parallel threads, then (3) merge pieces together.

Answer (score 0):

I finally used Gdal rasterize tool, passing polygons as shapefiles, and it works quite well and fast.